# Is using try-catch necessary for delete[] or delete operation in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, delete-operator

We are developing an application in Visual studio 2005, in code review i got this question from reviewer for the below code snippet

```
void FreeResourceForElements(void)
{
    try
    {
        delete[] m_cpMemPool;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // statement for printing error message in log
    }
}
```

As per the reviewer, In C++ language, delete or delete[] operation is guaranteed not to throw an exception, Hence using try-catch here is not needed and catch block becomes a dead code. However when i searched in internet for any standard reference to confirm his view, unfortunately i could not find any. so i am placing this question here. Please advise.

Comment: It's a common convention that destructors don't throw, and in C++ and later the default is that they don't. But still it depends entirely on the class at hand. So there is no formal guarantee that a `delete` doesn't throw, though there can and most likely will be such an in-practice guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

`delete[]` calls the destructor of each array element. If your code base has a rule that destructors must be `noexcept` or must already handle exceptions to prevent them from propagating out of the destructor (and that rule is actually enforced), then it is not necessary to wrap `delete[]` in a try-catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, if the type of the array object is a built in type (char) then is it required?

Comment: @VKrishnaRaoRacharla In that case it cannot throw an exception